# Using opencv Sparsematrix with msvc 2010 64 bits

Tags: c++, opencv, destructor, sparse-matrix

I keep having crash when the destructor of cv::SparseMat_ is called in my code. The 32 bits version of my program works well and i can compute extremely huges matrix without any problem, but in 64bits a simple code like this crashs at the end of the scope :

```
{
   int size[] = {100, 100};
   cv::SparseMat_<double> sparseMat(2, size);
} // crash
```

I tryed with the versions 2.45 and 2.48 of opencv (with the precompiled binairies and with the ones compiled by myself) with no changes at all and i am very confident about my makefile configuration.

Is anyone has already experimented a simular bug ?

Comment: I am using 2.48 and 64-bit Windows. Your code works fine with me. I don't think there is anything wrong with this piece of code. It must be something else. Could you paste a more complete code here?

Comment: By the way, if you look at the sample code on this page [SparseMatrix_](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id9). It is basically the same as what you have.